# Positive integers satisfying $a + b = c + d$ and $ab\vert cd$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I need to determine wheather there exist odd integers $a,b,c,d>1$ satisfying $a + b = c + d$ and $ab\mid cd$.

(Excluding the trivial cases, $a=c$ or $a=d$)

Any help is appreciated.

I have tried elementary methods but none works. I am searching for a more complicated method to help me determine but can't seem to find.

Thanks!

Comment: Suppose they are all equal.

Comment: I edited the question, I meant except that trivial case.. thanks

Comment: Your edit does not remove trivial cases.  Take $a=2,b=1,c=1,d=2$.

Comment: Yes I hope I edited it correct now thanks again

Comment: @Oren, you final edit (now undone) changed the problem substantially.  It would be better to ask it as a brand new question.  (The new question can link to this one with an explanation that you had omitted a restriction that was important for your needs.)

Comment: @BarryCipra I just rewrote the question, didn't undo the edit. But you're right.

Comment: thanks I will do that

Comment: Look at the new parametric infinite set of solutions

Comment: @barto, sorry, all I saw was the OP's addition at the end had disappeared.  I would recommend someone do a rollback to the version that had attracted valid answers. Although maybe at this point it's unnecessary to do anything.

Comment: Ok I'll just leave it here. Thanks all

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take $(a,b,c,d)=(3,18k+9,6k+3,12k+9)$ for $k\in \mathbb N$ and $3|k$, to get infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I edited the question again (hopefully last time) it is a part of a bigger question I need to solve,and It didn't work when one of them is 1

Comment: I'm thinking to find a solution

Comment: can you explain how to see that the quotient is an integer? Thanks!

Comment: Note that $ab=9.3.(2k+1)$, and $cd=9.(4k+3).(2k+1)$

Comment: How did you arrive at this answer? Could you explain your problem-solving process?

Comment: still a problem with the "extra 3" in $ab$..

Comment: When $3|k$, then $3|4k+3$...

Comment: Oh right Thanks a lot! I am also very curious of the process that got you to this solution :))

Comment: I recommend you to read the book "An Introduction to Diophantine Equations A Problem Based Approach-Titu Andreescu,Dorin Andrica,Ion Cucurezeanu"

Comment: Great thanks again